# How to Customize WooCommerce Coupon Error Messages and Display in a Different Location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with WooCommerce and trying to customize the way coupon error messages are displayed. Specifically, I want to:
[image: picture]

Customize the default WooCommerce coupon error messages.

1. Exclude displaying these messages in their default location.
2. Display the customized error messages in a specific div elsewhere on the page.
3. So far, I have managed to exclude the default messages using the woocommerce_add_error filter in my functions.php:

```
    function customize_wc_errors( $error )
{
  $excluded_phrases = [
    'Coupon code already applied!',

  ];

  foreach ($excluded_phrases as $phrase)
  {
    if (strpos($error, $phrase) !== false)
    {
      return '';
    }
  }

  return $error;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'customize_wc_errors' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the woocommerce_coupon_error filter.
Here's how :

```
function customize_coupon_error_message( $err, $err_code, $coupon )
{
  $messages = array(
    'coupon_apply_error' => __('This coupon cannot be applied.'),
    'coupon_minimum_error' => __('You need to spend more to use this coupon.'),
    // Add more custom error messages here
  );

  $message = isset( $messages[$err_code] ) ? $messages[$err_code] : $err;

  // Display the customized error message
  echo '<div class="custom-error-message">' . $message . '</div>';

  // Return an empty string to exclude the default error message
  return '';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error', 'customize_coupon_error_message', 10, 3 );
```

You can define your own custom error messages in the $messages array. The filter function then checks if the error code matches one of the custom messages and displays it in a specific div with the class "custom-error-message"...

Comment: but how do i choose where custom-error-message div will be displayed?

Comment: I just said it! I don't have your full code but you can do something like this :

Use JavaScript to select the div and append it to a specific location in the page. here is how you can use jQuery to append the div to a specific container:
`
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.custom-error-message').appendTo('#my-container');
});
`

So in above code, the ```custom-error-message``` div will be appended to the element with the ID ```my-container```. You can replace my-container with the ID of the element where you want to display the div.

Comment: With your solution, it will first be displayed in the default location (the 'woocommerce-error' wrapper) and, after a delay, it will then be displayed in #my-container.